# PHP Resize image and save Transparent PNG

Tags: php, png, transparent

**I've a png image uploading script in my website and i'm scaling down the large images to small size and i'm using this code but it loses the transparent background**

```
$image = $tmp; // Uploaded Image
$maxImgWidth = 224;
$src = imagecreatefrompng($image);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
$newwidth = $maxImgWidth;
$newheight = ($height / $width) * $newwidth;
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagepng($newImage, "../thumb/$name_after-$code.$ext", 1);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

**This code makes the image without transparency :**

[image]

**And i want with transparent background like this one :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I have **no experience in PHP** but after I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271742/create-a-transparent-png-file-using-php), I think you may need add the transparent colour **after** you set the **save alpha is true**

```
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);
```

**if still cannot try** add this after `imagecolorallocatealpha()`,

```
imagecolortransparent($image, $color);
```

Comment: try add `imagecolortransparent($image, $color);`  after imagecolorallocatealpha()?

Comment: after add the `imagecolortransparent($image, $color);` only work?

Comment: No it worked from the first code you posted, i didn't change the ($img) with my variable($image) so it didn't work first time but when i changed it, it worked! Thanks again :) I appreciate your help.

Comment: actually my first post variable is $img but I change it to $image after I found yours is different. You are welcome, I learn something also. ^^